# Issue with Cache expiration on JBOSS DATA GRID

Tags: datagrid, openshift, distributed-caching

I am using JBOSS Datagrid (RED HAT XPAAS DATA GRID IMAGE) for distributed caching. Running into issues in getting the cache expiration to work. Based on the documentation (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-xpaas/0/single/red-hat-xpaas-data-grid-image/), it looks like all I have to do is specify `<CACHE_NAME>_CACHE_EXPIRATION_LIFESPAN` environment variable with the time in milliseconds. 
Looks like this isn't working. The cache is never expiring which is the default behavior. Wondering if anyone has run into similar issue or knows what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I realized is that irrespective of how we define the cache name, we need to define the environment variable that manages the cache settings in ALL CAPS. All I had to do to get the cache expiration to work is to rename the env variable to all upper case and it worked. Isnt too clear from the documentation. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: If you wrote the cache settings in small , it din't give the error when you call build method from client? or while starting data grid server?

Comment: the grid server should ideally give exception if there is something wrong with configuration... i am wondering why the server din't reported any errors in your case